# How can I modify the mesh of a linked character?

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, armature, groups

I have a fun problem:

In `character.blend` I have an armature and a mesh with shapekeys inside a Group. In a new scene (`pose.blend`) I have Linked in Group. I then created a proxy (Make Proxy) and posed out the character. Now I'm noticing a small problem that I would like to fix for just this `pose.blend` file. How can I modify the mesh?

In my Outliner (under *All Scenes*) I have:

- `character` which is just an empty containing everything that was in
  the group, however I cannot select the mesh or armature
- `character_proxy` which is the armature that I was able to move and
  manipulate

Some things I've tried:

1. Making local the whole group. I still cannot select the mesh
2. Making local the objects in the outliner, the mesh is no where to be found and I cannot edit `character` (it is stuck in Object mode.)
3. Running *Make Single User* <kbd>U</kbd> on `character` or `character_proxy`, there is still no mesh, and the mesh is not selectable from Groups Outliner.

Now I did successfully do this (thanks Olson from #blender irc!):

1. Select `character` from the outliner and *Make Proxy* the mesh
2. Make the mesh local and then manipulate it.

This works but the problem is the mesh is in T-Pose (ignoring the armature.) I can 'fix' the pose but it is cumbersome (since it is not posed out.)

Any help would be appreciated :D!

Answer (score 4):

Just link in the character rig's group as usual, then append the object. It will be shown read-only in the outliner. To make it editable, select the object through the outliner, then convert both the object itself and its mesh to local instance.

[image: 1a]

Using *Make Proxy* for mesh object isn't recommended, because it will lose all modifiers and vertex groups:

[image: 2a]

Answer (score 4):

If you still want it linked and be able to switch between the two scenes easily, go to Blender Preferences (Ctrl+Alt+U), click on Addons and search for **Edit Linked Library**. You will see an addon called that. Enable it, and in the 3D View (with a linked object selected) go to the Tools menu (**T**-Key on your keyboard) and at the bottom will be a small thing where you can switch back to the original model and back.

[image: Edit Linked Library Addon]

[image: Edit Linked Library Buttons]